# Bind javascript events to MVC controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

What is the best way to bind Javascript events to my custom MVC controls? My initial thought is to create the controls using Html Helpers which give them a CSS class that signifies what kind of control they are.  Then, on `document.ready`, I'll use jQuery to select all such controls by their class name and bind their events.

However, I'm concerned about the speed of selecting from the entire dom by class name.  I've read (and experienced) how slow this can be, especially in IE8 which we need to target for this project.

I could select by IDs by creating a js file for each page, but I'd rather not do this, as it's a complicated web app with lots of pages.  I'd rather have one js file for each type of control that gets included in a view if the view contains at least one of that type of control.

Are CSS classes my best option?  Any other ideas?  I'm using MVC3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to try it out with classes and test the performance. If you are not satisfied, switch to IDs. I use class selectors all the time and don't find them terribly slow  in any browser. When you give jquery a context to search in, things are quite fast. For example:

```
$('#controls .control').whatever();
```

Or

```
$('.control', '#controls').whatever();
```

Sizzle is great at optimizing these things to be fast.

**Edit:** Here is a good reference for jQuery performance tips in general (notice #5): 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/

Comment: Thanks, but I can't select by context as the controls could be anywhere on the page.  Just to be clear, I'm not going to be able to select "per page", it's got to be a generic methodology that works across the web app.  See my edit.

Comment: @JoshNoe I don't understand why you can't select by ID without creating a js file for each page. Is it just because you don't want to include code for controls that aren't on the page? If so, then it sounds like you're on the right track when you say that you'd rather have one js file for each control that gets included in a view if the view contains at least one of that type of control. Can't you do that and select by ID?

Comment: How would my js file know what IDs to select by?  For instance, say I have a control type "CustomDropDown" on two pages.  One of the pages has a CustomDropDown with Id "companies", and another page has one with Id "racecars".  Both of these pages will use the same "CustomDropDown.js" file, which won't have any knowledge of these ids.

Comment: @JoshNoe You would only need to give them different IDs if they are expected to function differently. Otherwise, if your js is going to treat them the same, you could just give them an id of "CustomDropDown".

Comment: @Ibstr Thanks but this isn't really practical in this case for a few reasons.  For one, I'll likely have multiple of the same type of control on the page (I guess I could name the second "CustomDropDown2" and iterate until I don't find, but this smells).  More importantly, I will likely need page-specific client-side functionality on these controls, so I'll want to access them by id in the page's js, so I'll want more descriptive ids.

Comment: @JoshNoe I see what you are saying. You certainly don't want to get into the game of assigning dynamic IDs (like you said, that smells!). It sounds like you have to use class selectors. I don't think there is anything wrong with that, especially when you know there won't be 1000 dropdown menus on the page. Just keep your `<script>` tags at the bottom of your `<body>` so that the js parsing doesn't block the document parsing! Sorry we couldn't figure something slick out for this; again, I really doubt you'll take any substantial performance hit here. Good luck!